# debug eval in php.module line 80

Tags: 7

in line 80 of php.module there is an "eval" command that executes the code passed through the php fields.

If there is an error, you get information on its type, but not the code that generated that.

Is there a way to find which php code is causing the error in line 80 of php.module?

Comment: Have you enabled PHP error reporting and looked in the log files: https://www.drupal.org/node/158043 ?

Comment: yes, but it doesn't provide the information I'm searching for

Comment: From official PHP documentation: "[**Caution:** The eval() language construct is *very* dangerous](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) *(...)*" One of the problems with it is that when PHP engine fails, it fails. Not everything generates errors you can catch. So there is no real option to catch and report bug. And because code passed is not a function, extracting it from any kind of backtrace would be really hard. There always is xdebug, of course.

Comment: I know that it's dangerous, thank you.
And thank you also for confirm me that it is not possible to catch the errors...