# How do I debug "unexpected % in php_eval()"?

Tags: debugging

While testing with PHP 7 a site, which works fine with PHP 5.5, I get this error on some pages:

> *ParseError* : syntax error, unexpected '%' in `php_eval()` (line 7 of ..\modules\php\php.module(80) : eval()'d code).

I have no idea where to search that %. It could be in code, or a token in panels or anything. I already read comments in [this similar question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/121442/debug-eval-in-php-module-line-80), but maybe someone got same bug while testing PHP 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is from php code in a text field.

> Speaking of debugging, errors in eval()’d codes throw up error
>   messages that don’t provide much help in identifying or locating the
>   error. There’s a good chance you might have to go through your
>   database manually to find and fix the error. Such errors might even be
>   fatal in certain instances, for example, if the error is in a block
>   that is displayed on all pages.

Source: http://valuebound.com/resources/blog/enabling-php-filter-in-drupal-7-core-what-can-go-wrong